# Is a "for loop" the best method to use for my simple random image app?

Tags: ios, image, random, uiimageview

I want to have a random image refresh every 10 seconds after I load an app. Similar to a screensaver.I need to trigger the start of a loop or something. Where in the .m file do I have to put the loop function please.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)randomize:(id)sender

    {

{ int randomimages = rand()% 5;
    switch (randomimages) {
        case 0:
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];
            break;

        case 1:
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];
            break;

        case 2:
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];
            break;

        case 3:
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];

            break;

        case 4:
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];

            break;
    }
    }
}

-(IBAction)randomize2:(id)sender

{int randomimages = rand()% 5;
            switch (randomimages) {
                case 0:
                    imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];
                    break;

                case 1:
                    imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];
                    break;

                case 2:
                    imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];
                    break;

                case 3:
                    imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];

                    break;

                case 4:
                    imageView2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"...jpg"];

                    break;


            }
        }


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a for loop, use an `NSTimer` to call your method which selects and updates the image. Start the timer in `viewDidAppear:` and `invalidate` it in `viewDidDisappear:`.

Also, consider naming your images as numbers so you don't need a switch statement. Instead you could have something like:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", randomimages]];
```

And you can use the count of images to limit the random number generation.

Answer (score 0):

As @Wain mentioned before you should use NSTimer. Here is another way to do it. Every NSObject (your controller and every class is instance of NSObject class) have a method:
performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

In you case use can use it:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad {
      [self performSelector:@selector(changeImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
 }
```

and inside changeImage method

```
-(void)changeImage {

    ... // here you will show image

    [self performSelector:@selector(changeImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}
```

This will make a infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help with this the images now randomize every 10 seconds perfectly very helfpul:)

Answer (score 0):

I can also recommend you to put the images in an array and then get them with ObjectAtIndex

```
imageBgs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1.png",@"4.png", nil];
int index = arc4random() % [imageBgs count];
UIImage *bla = [imageBgs objectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: Saving all the images to an array would greatly increase the memory footprint. Better to save an array of image name strings, and load the image name randomly.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a for loop is NOT the way to go.

anatoliy_v probably has the best suggestion, using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay.

As far as how to select the image:

I would create an array of your image filenames. Then each time your changeImage method fires, pick a random index and load the image with that name.

However, this method would cause you to sometimes display the same image twice in a row, or possibly several times in a row.

A fancy approach would be to create a "feeder" array with all your filenames in it. Then copy the feeder array into a mutable array. Fetch one filename at a time from the mutable array and remove it. When the mutable array is empty, reload it from the feeder array. Something like this (based on the code from anatoliy_v) :

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad 
{
  self.feederArray = @[
    @"file1",
    @"file2",
    @"file3",
    @"file4",
    @"file5",
    @"file6",
    @"file7",
    @"file8",
    @"file9",
    @"file10"
  ];
  self.randomArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [self.feederArray count]];
  [self changeImage]; //load a random image immediately and start the timer to change it
 }


-(void)changeImage 
{
  //If our randomArray is empty, populate it from the feeder array.
  if ([self.randomArray count] == 0)
    [self.randomArray addObjectsFromArray: self.feederArray];

  //Select randomly from the array of remaining random images.
  int index = arc4random_uniform([self.randomArray count]);
  NSString *filename = self.randomArray[index];
  [self.randomArray removeObjectAtIndex: index];

  //Now show the image who's name is in filename
  //...

  //Finally, queue up another call to changeImage 10 seconds later to load a new image.
  [self performSelector:@selector(changeImage) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}
```